# Set correct filepath ajax load()

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I try to use Smarty. Now I have problem with correct filepath.
All code now works. I exactly don't know how to make **DIR**.
What I have:

**Smarty**

*CartController.php*

```
/**
* 
* Add product to cart
* 
* @param integer id GET - ID of adding product
* @return json   info about operation (success, number of elements in cart)
*/
function addtocartAction(){
    $itemId = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : NULL;
    if (! $itemId) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $resData = array();

    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = $itemId;
        $resData['cntItems'] = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $resData['success'] = 1;
    } else {
        $resData['success'] = 0;
    }

    echo json_encode($resData);
}

/**
* 
* Making cart page
* 
* @link /cart/
*/
function indexAction($smarty) {
    $itemsIds = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();

    $rsCategories = getAllMainCatsWithChildren();
    $rsKits8 = getKitsByCat(4);
    $rsKits16 = getKitsByCat(5);
    $rsSortsHoney = getLastSortsHoney();
    $rsSortsHoneyKits8 = getAllKits8WithSorts();
    $rsSortsHoneyKits16 = getAllKits16WithSorts();
    $rsCartKits = getKitsFromArray($itemsIds);
    $rsCount = getCountKitsFromArray($itemsIds);

    $smarty->assign('pageTitle', 'Cart');
    $smarty->assign('rsCategories', $rsCategories);
    $smarty->assign('rsKits8', $rsKits8);
    $smarty->assign('rsKits16', $rsKits16);
    $smarty->assign('rsSortsHoney', $rsSortsHoney);
    $smarty->assign('rsSortsHoneyKits8', $rsSortsHoneyKits8);
    $smarty->assign('rsSortsHoneyKits16', $rsSortsHoneyKits16);
    $smarty->assign('rsCartKits', $rsCartKits);
    $smarty->assign('rsCount', $rsCount);



    loadTemplate($smarty, 'cart');

}
```

Then I make this function

**JavaScript**

```
function addToCart(itemId) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/cart/addtocart/" + itemId + '/',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data['success']) {
          $('#cartCntItems').html(data['cntItems']);
          $('#from-ajax').load('http://fashionhoney.local/cart/');
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $(document).on('click', '.addToCart', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      addToCart(this.id.split('_')[1]);
  });
```

Now I really don't know how to set correct path on this line

```
$('#from-ajax').load('http://fashionhoney.local/cart/');
```

How I can configure the **DIR** automatically?

Comment: When it goes to `http://fashionhoney.local/cart/` it recieve file **cart.tpl** with code, that work with database.

Comment: Okay, I solve this problem. If you have same problem and want solve it yourself please read about **smarty fetch**. On this [link](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=91382#91382) I write my version of solution. . If anyone has the better solution please write me. Thanks